# A list model field for Models.Model

Tags: python, django

I'm looking for a field that I can use to be defined in my model which is essentially a list because it'll be used to store multiple string values. Obviously CharField cannot be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are describing a many-to-one relationship. This should be modeled by an extra `Model` having a `CharField` to store the string and `ForeignKey` to your main `Model` (as @Kujira has already pointed out):

```
class YourModel(models.Model):
    pass

class String(models.Model):
    your_model = models.ForeignKey('YourModel', related_name='strings')
    string = models.CharField('String', max_len=..., ...)
```

Now you can add strings to an instance of `YourModel`:

```
ym = YourModel.objects.create()
ym.strings.create(string='string1')
ym.strings.create(string='string2')
```

Comment: is it valid to have two related namest a model. I.e. if 'String' is already a model I have and already has a foreign key to 'YourModel' via another related name, can I just modify it to your_model = models.ForeignKey('YourModel', related_name = 'whatever',  related_name='strings') ?

Comment: No. You can have only one `related_name` per FK-relation, and those names mustn't collide for different FK's pointing to the same Model. Just give the string Model name and related_name unique values.

Comment: Oh okay so your_model = models.ForeignKey('YourModel', related_name = 'whatever') and your_model2 = models.ForeignKey('YourModel', related_name = 'strings') would be valid ?

Comment: Yes. If those fields are defined on different models, you can call them both `your_model`, but the `related_name` must be different, as is the case in your example.

Comment: I've decided to just use a single one for both, I'm sure that'll work. In my view I'm thinking about using an array for the appropriate data type to do i.e. record = [] then if when entered in the loop i can do record = ym.strings.create(topic = strings.name) because I need to pass the results to the template

Answer (score 0):

You'll define another model that has foreign key to the main model.

Comment: You might want to elaborate that with a short example that contains the FK and the required `CharField`.

Comment: @schwobaseggl I'm currently on phone, so I didn't bother. Feel free to edit and upgrade the answer.